# Gson: handle json object field that can return different primitive types?

Tags: java, android, gson

An API my application is communicating with sends responses that look like this:

```
{
    id:12345,
    active:1
}
```

The problem is that older versions of the API sends the response field as a boolean value rather than an int like so

```
{
    id:12345,
    active:false,
}
```

With Gson, how can I handle both with no knowledge of which version will be returned?

Comment: Take it as "Object"..

Comment: you can check both in if condition like as if(1 || false){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a [CustomDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) for boolean and when ever a boolean is encountered inside any object, gson will try to deserialize with the rules that you defined.

```
@Data
class JsonTestClass {
    Boolean active = new Boolean(true);
    Integer id;
}

class BooleanJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = json.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        if (jsonPrimitive.isBoolean()) {
            return jsonPrimitive.getAsBoolean();
        } else {
            return jsonPrimitive.getAsInt() == 0 ? false : true;
        }
    }
}

// TempJson
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, new BooleanJsonDeserializer()).create();

    System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{id:12345,active:1}", JsonTestClass.class).getActive());
    System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{id:12345,active:0}", JsonTestClass.class).getActive());
    System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{id:12345,active:false}", JsonTestClass.class).getActive());
    System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{id:12345,active:true}", JsonTestClass.class).getActive());
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: I would mark this answer as the best one. Just a little note. The name of `BooleanJsonDeserializer` is closer to the description of what that class does than `BooleanTypeAdapter` is since `TypeAdapter`s in Gson are stream-oriented whilst `JsonDeserializer`s are tree-oriented.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Changed the name :) Used TypeAdapter as you register with GSON as a TypeAdapter

Answer (score 0):

PFB the way to handle this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject obj = gson.fromJson("{    id:12345,    active:1}", JsonObject.class);
    JsonPrimitive prim = obj.get("active").getAsJsonPrimitive();
    if(prim.isBoolean()){
        System.out.println("boolean");
    }else{
        System.out.println("number");
    }
}
```